# Passing template name by condition using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout-2.0

If i have a div section with class container as below where i need to populate a template based on dropdown selected. How can i do that using knockout.js.

```
    <div class="container"></div>

    <!--Dropdown-->
    <select>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>

    <!--Templates-->
    <script type="text/html" id="A-template">
      <span data-bind="text:Value"></span>
    </script>
    <script type="text/html" id="B-template">
      <span data-bind="text:Value"></span>
    </script>
    <script type="text/html" id="A-template">
      <span data-bind="text:Value"></span>
    </script>
```

Comment: I suggest you start by reading through the documentation on templates. It contains a section on [dynamically choosing which template is used](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-5-dynamically-choosing-which-template-is-used) which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a computed to calculate the template name:

```
this.SelectionTemplate = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.Value() + "-template";
});
```

Your template binding would look like this:

```
data-bind="template: { name: SelectionTemplate, data: $root }"
```

Here is a JSFiddle Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Shce/1/